# Error while loading data from ADLS Gen2 to Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am trying to perform a copy activity from ADLS Gen2 to Azure Synapse warehouse using polybase direct copy. while copying i am getting the error like :

" Please make sure SQL DW has access to ADLS Gen2". but why does it need access to ADLS Gen2 when data factory can take care of it? and also how do i give that access if i need to give that.

Thanks.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/linked-server-to-synapse-sql-to-implement-polybase-like-scenarios-in-managed-instance/

Comment: Is this a staged copy or a direct copy?

Comment: I can success copy, you can check my answer. Maybe there is something differences bettween your and mine?

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I can success copy.

You can check the whether the settings is different bettween your and mine.

This is the firewall settings of my sql server:

[image]

I didn't set any firewall limit, I allow my client IP and other azure service to access my sql server.

And this is my copy activity:

[image]
[image]

This pipeline works fine:

[image]
[image]